# Initializing Firebase crashlytics in android

Tags: android, firebase, crashlytics

I have migrated Fabric Crashlytics to Firebase Crashlytics in my android project. While using fabric, in activity class I have used below line,

```
Fabric.with(this, new Crashlytics());
```

But after migration, what is the exact replacement of this in Firebase Crashlytics.

Thanks in Advance..

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-started?platform=android#java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to follow the Firebase tutorial when activating the Crashlytics. You don't need any code to initialize Crashlytics, it's automatic.

The only thing you need, following the tutorial, is to make an intentional crash, api will detect it and your crashlytics will be connected.

Please, follow the next documentation: https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-started?hl=es&platform=android

Comment: You are welcome, it's really easy, I did it some days ago, the api didn't detect the first crash but then, started the app again, generate the crash and everything was connected.