# Firebase Crashlytics does not find flutter android or iOS app

Tags: android, ios, firebase, flutter, crashlytics

[image of validation shown to me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5qTSP.png)

I followed the official docs for both Android and iOS and I do not have any further clue what the possible problem could be.

Link to the docs: https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-started?authuser=0&platform=ios

I added for android everything as stated in the build.gradle & app/build.gradle files.

Firebase Analytics works completely fine for me!

[Crashlytics instance deprecated? what to use instead?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ISdew.png)

If you have any idea what I am doing wrong please help me ;)

Best, Alex

Comment: Crashlytics, in native android, don't need any code to make it works, just add dependency in gradle. Did you crash your app to perform the conection?

Comment: Thanks for your answer @BogdanAndroid
I thought just for the connection to the dashboard there is no crashing required?

Comment: also I found this tutorial specific for flutter and crashlytics:
https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/crashlytics/usage/

Comment: adding the code from this tutorial did not help either.

Comment: Crash is fundamental to connect the crashlytics api to the server. Sometimes it takes a little bit more time to conect or repeat the intentional crash multiple times. https://stackoverflow.com/a/64204174/14327871

Comment: ah this might be the problem then! I give it a last try!

Comment: that was it! thanks @BogdanAndroid! It works now for Android and iOS!!

Comment: Nice! Was easy!